# Configuring virtualenvwrapper on Centos6

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, centos6

I have a VPS running Centos6, which has Python2.6 pre-installed. I have installed Python3.6 on this path

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

I have installed virtualenv using pip which is at

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

I then created a virtualenvwrapper.sh file under /etc/profile.d (I have been advised this is what I need to do) which is generating an error on start up:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for    
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

virtualenvwrapper is located at /usr/local/bin/python3.6/site-packages

As I am novice using Linux I didn't think the code in the file virtualenvwrapper.sh (under /etc/profile.d)

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

**UPDATE**

I have now edited the virtualenvwrapper.sh file under /etc/profile.d as follows

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.6
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

This has worked fine - I can now run the virtualenvwrapper commands. Is it pk that all of the start up files have been placed in the .virtualenvs folder (eg initalize, postactivate etc) - which means that when I create a virtualenvironment, that will be placed alongside these files? Is there a better way to do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your second question: this is how `virtualenvwrapper` works. It puts global initialization files into `~/.virtualenvs`; these files will be run (sourced, actually) for every virtual env. Also there will be separate initialization files for every virtual env.

Having all virtual envs in `~/.virtualenvs` helps `virtualenvwrapper` to manage all envs.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. If that's ok to have the environments mixed in with the files I referenced, that's fine by me!